# Perl script to monitor oracle alert log file

Tags: oracle, perl

We have customized monitoring Perl script picks up timing data to monitor alert log from oracle alert log file when it is in the format “Wed May 29 23:55:19 2013”. But whereas for Oracle 10.2.0.5 databases oracle writes time zone information also along with date like “Thu May 30 01:30:43 ADT 2013” in alert log file.

We are using below script to get the timestamp in yyyymmddhhmmss. But the same script has been failing when alertlog file has date format with timezone.

```
sub make_timestamp
{
    my ($day_name,$month_name,$day,$time_stamp,$year,$timestamp);
chomp @_[0];
($day_name,$month_name,$day,$time_stamp,$year) = split (/ +/,@_[0]);
($hour,$min,$sec) = split(/:/,$time_stamp);
## $day = $padded_number{$day} if ($day < 10);
$timestamp = $year . $month{$month_name} . $day . $hour . $min . $sec;
return $timestamp;
}
```

Can you please assist me to fix this code?

Comment: You should consider using a proper module for handling time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sub make_timestamp
{
 chomp $_[0];
  my ($day_name,$month_name,$day,$time_stamp,$timezone,$year) = split (/ +/,$_[0]);
  $time_stamp =~ s/://g;
  ## $day = $padded_number{$day} if ($day < 10);
  my $timestamp = $year . $month{$month_name} . $day . $time_stamp;
  return $timestamp;
}
```

I tailored a little bit. Use `$_[0]` instead of `@_[0]`. Also the declaration and definition of the variables can be put into one line. I would remove `$timestamp` variable and return the composed value immediately.

Anyway I would suggest you to add `use strict; use warnings;` to the beginning of the script. It helps to reduce the possible errors.